arcpy.conversion.RasterToOtherFormat creates a black TIFF
I'm using ArcGIS Pro 3.3.0 on Windows 11
In below code, when I enable the arcpy.env.cellSize and arcpy.env.extent variables I get a black raster as output and it is the correct size and the correct (top-left-corner) position.
If I disable these 2 environment variables, the output TIFF is visible (not black) but it has cellsize=1 and is positioned at 0,0
The input image is from a mobile phone and does have Lat/Long coordinates.
Any ideas on how to solve this?
arcpy.env.outputCoordinateSystem = srs_out
arcpy.env.geographicTransformations = tfm
arcpy.env.resamplingMethod = 'CUBIC'
arcpy.env.compression = 'NONE'
    xmin = inpX
    xmax = inpX + (cellsize * width)
    ymax = inpY
    ymin = inpY - (cellsize * height)
    exts = f'{xmin} {ymin} {xmax} {ymax}'
#    arcpy.env.cellSize = cellsize
#    arcpy.env.extent = exts
    arcpy.conversion.RasterToOtherFormat(image, dir_in, 'TIFF')
    arcpy.DefineProjection_management(tif, srs_out)



Have you tried excluding extent but keep cell size and then opposite to see what happens? Add your response to your question not as a reply to this comment.

Is it really a "black" TIFF, or is it a TIFF with large bit depth, valid values, and no statistics?

Sounds like the input may have GPS coordinates in its exif data, but is not georeferenced. So setting cellsize and extent makes ArcGIS try to read the input data from outside the bounds of the image so you get NoData/null in the output.  Perhaps try arcpy.management.Warp

Try Recalculate Statistics tool and re-add to your map. most probably it still remembers old value ranges and renders it accordingly even though you resampled as cubic.
